# How is Nescafé made?

Tags: instant

How is Nescafé (or any other instant coffee) made? Do they brew coffee and then dehydrate it (like they do it with instant soups)? Or is it done another way? What ingredients do they use to produce it?

Answer (score -2):

A quick [Google](https://www.google.ca/) search led me to [this](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-3/Instant-Coffee.html).
It's a very detailed site that explains everything you need.

Comment: Link-only answers [don't make for good answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) on Stack Exchange, because link rot will make your answer useless. We encourage answers to actually answer the question independently of their links, which usually means extracting the key information from that link and citing it. Imagine if the link goes dead tomorrow (it might): what do you need to include in this answer for it to not be totally useless?